# Apple wireless keyboard is outputting an " character when I expect an @ character

Tags: macos, mac

I just bought a Mac Mini and a wireless apple keyboard. Whenever I type Shift+2, expecting the `@` symbol to appear, I get a `"` character instead. How can I diagnose the problem and correct the mapping so Shift+2 produces the `@` symbol as expected?

Several other Shift keys in that row are also wrong:  6 is &, 7 is ', 8 is (, 9 is ), 0 is 0.

Comment: Is your specific question: how do I log in to my Mac with an email address when the Shift-2 key combination produces a " character and not an @ character?

Comment: Have you checked in System Preferences -> Language and Text -> Input Sources to be sure your keyboard is set to US (or another layout that in fact has @ above the 2 when shifted?)?

Comment: Yes, everything is set to US language and keyboard lang. My time zone is set to US. My question is why is the "at" symbol not working. I get a quotation mark instead. I think maybe the keyboard is broken.

Comment: Try a different keyboard - that should help you decide whether it is a hardware or software error.  Borrow a USB keyboard if possible.

Comment: Just hooked up my logitech keyboard and the @ key works! Now I:m trying the wireless apple keyboard. " ... Nope doesn:t work still. Guess it:s the keyboard?

Comment: Is it only the @ key which is wrong?  How about other Shift level keys in the number row?

Comment: 1 is ! 2 is " 3 is # 4 is $ 5 is % 6 is & 7 is ' 8 is ( 9 is ) 0 is 0

Answer (score 1):

For some reason your mini thinks the keyboard is a JIS (Japanese) keyboard "type".  This note might help:

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: We prefer to have answers which stand on their own and to not rely on external sources (links may break rendering the answer useless). Can you please edit the essential points of the linked article into your answer?

Comment: I'm just gonna go back and return the keyboard. This is beyond annoying.

Comment: Yep, got a new keyboard. Works flawlessly. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I have an refurbed macbook air with the exact problem as OP, built-in keyboard, fully upgraded to sierra, which is set to a US keyboard layout and nevertheless produces " for @.  Maybe it started life as JIS keyboard and someone switched the keys during refurb, I don't know.

After much searching and trying all the recommended solutions up to an including the SMC and PRAM reset hackery, nothing worked.  Trying the Karabiner approach some have suggested had no effect at all, BUT merely *running* [karabiner-elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) (with no configuration changes) fixes everything for me, apparently causing sierra to actually respect the US keyboard layout.

Answer (score -3):

Just experienced the same problem with shift+2 returning " on wireless apple keyboard connected to PC.
Out of curiosity I typed shift+" and this returned @.
Not a brilliant solution I know but at least it's workable.

Comment: That is a different issue - shift 2 on a PC is " - OP has Apple keyboard on OSX